# Making an object from a C dll in C++

Tags: c++, c, oop, constructor, dllexport

I have a C++ program which I call multiple C++ Dlls in it. Usually I make a simple class in the Dlls with a constructor and a destructor and do some initialization in the constructors. Then in the main program I make multiple objects from each Dlls' class and use them in **multiple threads**.

```
MyNamespcae::MyDllClass * MyObj = new MyNamespcae::MyDllClass(/*...inputs...*/);  # I make an object for each thread seperately
```

Now I have a **C** Dll that I'm calling in the main c++ program. I exported the **C** functions with  `__declspec(dllexport)` and use them **directly** in the main program. The problem here is that I have some global variables in the C Dll, so I can not use the Dll in multiple threads.

So my question is how can I do some object-oriented-like method (like what we do in C++) in the C dll to  call it in C++, from multiple threads? (*Note My question is about what I need to do in **C** not c++*)

Comment: Don't use static variables in your C-code. In C, you can use `malloc`, `free` and `realloc` for memory managenent. (Some hints: https://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html#fqa-8.7 )

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond That could be done if I declare the variables in c++ which I don't want too. I need to keep every thing related to C, just in the Dll, unless you mean something else.

Comment: Sure, I meant something else;) Here is an example: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/oop.html#S0004

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond The second link did the job, I upvoted the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link shared by **Lorinczy Zsigmond** which is: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/oop.html#S0004 solved my problem. I repeat it's content here for more convenience:

> Header-file: /* mytype.h */

```
#ifndef MYTYPE_H
#define MYTYPE_H

typedef struct MyType MyType; /* opaque */

MyType *MyType_Alloc (int par);
void    MyType_Release (MyType *mp);

int MyType_Operation1 (MyType *mp, int par1, int par2);

#endif
```

> source code: /* mytype.c */

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "mytype.h"

struct MyType {
    int somedata;
};

MyType *MyType_Alloc (int par) {
    MyType *mp= malloc (sizeof *mp);
    mp->somedata= par;
    return mp;
}

void MyType_Release (MyType *mp) {
    memset (mp, 0, sizeof *mp);
    free (mp);
}

int MyType_Operation1 (MyType *mp, int par1, int par2) {
    return mp->somedata + par1 + par2;
}
```

> test:/* mytypetest.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mytype.h"

int main (void) {
    MyType *mp= MyType_Alloc (20200000);
    int sum= MyType_Operation1 (mp, 100, 25);
    printf ("sum=%d\n", sum);
    MyType_Release (mp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, either these variables need to be global, or they don't.

If they do, then you have to properly synchronize, so you'll need to export from the C method not the variables, but rather functions which access these variables with proper synchronization.

If they don't need to be global, and you want to allocate one (or more) per thread, then you can just export 2 C functions for each such object type, `myobj_t new_dllobj(...)` and `delete_dllobj(myobj_t obj)`, which allocate & construct and destroy & release these objects.

Comment: Which is quite the same what @root wrote. Also Yossi Kreinin (in my first link). Nonetheless, if you have questions regarding the thread-synchronization (e.g. with pthread mutex) do ask them.

Comment: The link doesn't have synchronization, it just has the equivalent of what I called `new_dllobj()` and `delete_dllobj()`, And the question isn't clear on whether or not the globals actually need to be globals.

Comment: @root I misunderstood synchronization concept at first. Yes I can use sync methods (which I'm using outside the dll) but that would slow my program so it's off the table. I made the variables global to use them in multiple functions, but other than that, no they don't need to be global (which I removed the them with the help of the allocation function). Thanks.